# Bot Framework C# Luis Getting > Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request)

Tags: c#, botframework, azure-language-understanding

I need assistance with integrating my Luis App into C# Bot Framework Bot

When I add Luis App to my C# Microsoft Bot Framework chatbot and run in the emulator I get an exception.

*Exception: Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).*

A debugging post from another developer on Github suggested adding domain, which I have to my LuisModel (see below).  This did not resolve the issue.

*[LuisModel("", "", 
                domain: "australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com", Staging = true)]*

Stepping through the code, my locals seem correct when it calls the *new Dialog.RootLuisDialog()*  Here is a screen grab

[image]

**Message Controller Code Snippet**

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody] Activity activity)
{
    // check if activity is of type message
    if (activity.Type == ActivityTypes.Message)
    {
        await Conversation.SendAsync(activity, () => new Dialogs.RootLuisDialog());
    }
    else
    {
        HandleSystemMessage(activity);
    }
    var response = Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK);
    return response;
}
```

**Luis Dialog Class**

```
namespace HalChatBot.Dialogs
{
        [LuisModel("<MyLuisAppID>", "<MyLuisKey>", 
            domain: "australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com", Staging = true)]
        [Serializable]
        public class RootLuisDialog : LuisDialog<object>
        {
            [LuisIntent("")]
            [LuisIntent("None")]
            public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
            {
                await context.PostAsync("I am the Default intent");
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
            }

           [LuisIntent("Greeting")]
           public async Task Greeting(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
           {
                await context.PostAsync("I am the Greeting intent");
                context.Wait(MessageReceived);
           }
        }
}
```

Comment: HTTP error 400 means the server tells you it doesn't like what you sent (or doesn't understand it). You can use a tool such as fiddler to check if it sent additional info in the HTTP response body so you can fix your code.

Comment: Thanks @SimonMourier, Fiddler shows Model not published. Please publish your model before hitting the Endpoint.  I have published the Luis App and just went back and republished.  Any other ideas?

Comment: If it keeps telling you your model is published, nope, beside checking you published the proper model :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Ran fiddler, encrypted *400 (Bad Request)* which stated *Model not published. Please publish your model before hitting the endpoint*
2. Republished MyLuisApp
3. Removed staging from LuisModel `[LuisModel("<MyLuisAppID>", "<MyLuisKey>", domain: "australiaeast.api.cognitive.microsoft.com")]`

Now Luis integration is working.

Comment: The problem was that you were pointing to the staging environment, not the production one. 2nd step is not necessary, you just have to ensure that you use the same environments. (and also that you specified the domain if it's not Westus, and that your API Key is defined to the same domain)